How to convert image list and mask list to TensorFlow dataset?
I'm having trouble converting image and mask data into Dataset that can be used in keras.Model.
I have a list of 100 images with a shape of (100, 128, 128, 3)) and I have a list of 100 segmenation_masks with a shape of (100, 128, 128, 1))
Please look at the code below.
import cv2
from pycocotools import mask as maskUtils
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from pycocotools.coco import COCO
import numpy as np

from unet import *

coco_images_dir = '../dataset/images/'
coco_json_path = '../dataset/COCO_Football Pixel.json'
checkpoint_path = "unet3plus_ckpt.weights.h5"
export_path = "unet3plus_export.weights.h5"
input_size = [128, 128]
batch_size = 30

# Json 파일 로드
coco = COCO(coco_json_path)
img_ids = coco.getImgIds()
cat_ids = coco.getCatIds()
images = []
segmentation_masks = []
for img_id in img_ids:
    img = coco.loadImgs(img_id)[0]
    file_name = coco_images_dir + img['file_name']
    image = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(file_name), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = image.astype(np.float32) / 255.0
    image = tf.convert_to_tensor(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, input_size)
    images.append(image)
    annIds = coco.getAnnIds(imgIds=img_id, iscrowd=None)
    anns = coco.loadAnns(annIds)
    segmentation_mask = np.zeros((input_size[0], input_size[1], 1))
    for ann in anns:
        if 'segmentation' in ann:
            rle = coco.annToRLE(ann)
            mask = maskUtils.decode(rle)
            mask = tf.expand_dims(mask, axis=-1)
            mask = tf.convert_to_tensor(mask)
            mask = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(mask, tf.uint8)
            mask = tf.image.resize(mask, input_size)
            mask *= (cat_ids.index(ann['category_id']) + 1)
            segmentation_mask += mask
    segmentation_masks.append(segmentation_mask)

##################################################################
# What should I do with images and segmentation_masks?
##################################################################
dataset = ...

model = unet((input_size[0], input_size[1], 3), len(coco.getCatIds()))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(dataset, epochs=100,
          callbacks=ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path, save_weights_only=True, save_best_only=False))
model.save(export_path)

I searched and tried several methods like slice or TFRecord but to no avail. Using the above method, the loss was 'nan' and the accuracy was less than 1%.
On the other hand, if I loaded the data through tensorflow-dataset's load function, it worked fine.
What should I do with images and segmentation_masks?

Does this answer your question? How to join two tf.data.Dataset tensor slices?

That's correct about images, but the mask consists of a series of coordinate data, not an image file.

your mask is in rle format. that's also doable. option 1: transform the rle to image and save to disk. option 2: read rle format with tensorflow.
